# Do I need to use DTO or POCO

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dto

I have a windows service application. The clients are scattered in the different place in US. When the service is consumed, then the data is generated. Now I have to save the data populated by the clients to sql server 2008 r2.

For the database, I used Entity FrameWork code first to generate it. Now it is empty in tables.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext, IDisposable
{
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}

 public class Task
{
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
}
```

I am not sure the best pattern to save the data to db. Do I have to adopt data transfer object in somewhere to do it or save data directly?
 Code example demo is welcomed.

Comment: Your `Task` class is your DAO. Whatever you do on the Service end is unrelated, `Task` could be your DTO as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have some data,

```
Task t = new Task { Detail = ...  };

using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    context.Tasks.Add(t);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: -@Henk, I knew the code. But you meant not using DTO or DTO was already there in Entity definition? And do we need serialize the data?

Comment: No serialization necessary on this level. But I don't know what you want in `Detail`. `t` is a DTO.

Comment: So you meant if Detail is an onject rather than string: `public object Detail', then serialization maybe required?

Comment: Yes, or you map another class with EF.